# Backup all databases fails on external server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have the following script to backup all databases from an SQL instance

This works perfectly from my local PC but when I run it on an external server it fails with the following:

> master backup failed.
>   Exception calling "SqlBackup" with "1" argument(s): "Backup failed for Server 'SERVER2016'."

```cs
$SQLInstance = "Localhost"
$BackupFolder = "D:\Backups\"

$timeStamp = Get-Date -Format yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null

$srv = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $SQLInstance
$dbs = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database
$dbs = $srv.Databases

foreach ($Database in $dbs) {
  $Database.Name
  $bk = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup")
  $bk.Action = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupActionType]::Database
  $bk.BackupSetName = $Database.Name + "_backup_" + $timeStamp
  $bk.Database = $Database.Name
  $bk.CompressionOption = 1
  $bk.MediaDescription = "Disk"
  $bk.Devices.AddDevice($BackupFolder + "\" + $Database.Name + "_" + $timeStamp + ".bak", "File")

  try {
    $bk.SqlBackup($srv)
  } catch {
    $Database.Name + " backup failed."
    $_.Exception.Message
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not do it the DBA way? Install [Ola's backup scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/) and run the jobs with appropriate parameters.

Comment: Check account permissions, perhaps you don't have enough rights to back up master database.

Comment: Thanks that worked, looked like it wasnt using the NTSecurity account i thought it was, forcing it to use the SA account worked.